# How do i display post titles from the page i'm on and not all post titles from a category?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I currently have some code that displays a list of all post titles within a category on a page, this page is on a website that's built using wordpress.

I'm unsure how to edit this so that it only displays post titles that appear on that page.

This is my current code for the page template:

```
<?php
            $backup = $post; //backup current object
            $current = $post->ID; //current page ID

            ?>

            <?php
            global $post; //tells WordPress we want all the data related to the current post
            $thisCat = get_the_category(); //variable filled with the category ID(s) for the current post
            $currentCategory = $thisCat[0]->cat_ID; // variable that is filled with the first category ID from the list
            $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=700&order=DESC&orderby=ID&category=' . $currentCategory . '&exclude=' . $current); //variable that makes a loop that displays two posts in decending order based on their ID numbers from the category defined in $currentCategory
            foreach($myposts as $post) : //creates a loop that sets the ID value of $post to the ID value of $mypost
            setup_postdata($post); //sets up the postdata (so all the content) of the new post
                ?>

                <h2><?php echo the_title(); ?></h2>



            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

to clarify eat menu item is dealt with as a post.

So to be clear **how can I display a list of post titles from a category ONLY if they appear on the page currently being viewed?**

Comment: I don't understand where you want the list to appear. I guess when you talk about a _page_ you don't mean a wordpress page: this seems more a code for a single post template. Please clarify your goal.

Comment: thanks for the reply @d79 , I've added some more info to the question. Hopefully that's helpful to you.

Comment: you could insert in an array every post you're showing while you're going through them, and then you'll have your list for the bottom